# Always Allow Background Location Android 11

Tags: java, android

I'm currently working on an app that requires users to have background location turned on as it is a core element.

Currently the app requests location and functions properly, but the user must manually go into settings to change to allow always. However, our users are generally not technically-savvy individuals, so I would like to make it so they can click allow always right when prompted for location.

I have been researching this topic for a few hours now and I cannot find a simple solution that doesn't require use of a library. According to Google's documentation, https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#request-background-location, this should be simple using the function `getBackgroundPermissionOptionLabel()`. I am unsure of the context to use this, and searching the function itself has not yielded any results.
I have also found their sample project,https://github.com/android/location-samples/tree/master, which includes `LocationUpdatesPendingIntent` that prompts the user for permissions but only shows a link to go to the location permissions settings page.

Currently here is exactly what we use for requesting the location permission, which is identical to what the example uses.

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
    new String[] {
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
        },
    REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: It's not possible on Android 11.